# I don´t understand: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'

Tags: java, android

I don't understand this error:

Error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$PrintHelperStubImpl.class

Code:

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'){exclude module: 'support-v4'}    
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'){exclude module: 'support-v4'}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: remove `{exclude module: 'support-v4'}`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line `compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')` (and probably `{exclude module: 'support-v4'}`). It is probably the `android/support/v4` library, which is already inside the default classpath when compiling android projects.

Comment: @ThiloLambert Well you should accept the answer then.